# How to find height of rectangular pyramid given base lengths and total length of edges?

Tags: optimization, systems-of-equations

So I have this problem that I'm trying to solve:

> A 144-cm wire is cut into 8 pieces and welded together to form a
>   pyramid with $b = 1.9a$ in the rectangular base. Determine the
>   dimensions a and b such that the pyramid’s volume is maximized. Define
>   a=4:0.01:14 and use this vector for calculating volume $V = abh/3$
>   (after expressing h in terms of a). 3 Use the function max to
>   determine the greatest volume.

Assuming it's a right pyramid, I know how to solve for everything but $h(a)$.
So I've tried to use the system of equations:

$144 = 2a + 2b + 4s$, given that s is one of the edges from the base to the point.

$b = 1.9a$

$s = \sqrt{h^2+r^2}$, given that r is the radius from the center of the base to a corner.

$r = \sqrt{(a/2)^2+(b/2)^2}$

which led me to:

$ h = 0.229416\sqrt{18.05a^2 - 1983.6a + 24624}$

I'm very confused though, because I solved it about three weeks ago the first time and calculated $h=3a$, which is much simpler and closer to what I would expect.

Comment: The pyramid is supposed to be a right pyramid?

Comment: MathJax hint:  If you put the argument of a square root in braces the top bar extends to cover.  So \sqrt {a^2+b^2} gives $\sqrt {a^2+b^2}$ instead of \sqrt a^2+b^2 which gives $\sqrt a^2+b^2$.  This works for many things like fractions, subscripts, superscripts, etc.  The stuff inside the braces is treated as a unit.

Comment: Thanks for the tip and the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$h=3a$ cannot be right as $h$ must be a decreasing function of $a$ over the range of interest

$$144=2a+2b+4s\\144=2a+3.8a+4\sqrt{\frac 14a^2+\frac{3.61}4a^2+h^2}\\
\frac 14(144-5.8a)^2=4.61a^2+4h^2\\h=\frac 12\sqrt{\frac 14(144-5.8a)^2-4.61a^2}\\
h=\frac12 \sqrt{3.8 a^2 - 417.6 a + 5184}$$

Comment: How did you get from equation a to equation b? Isn't $\sqrt{(1/4)*a^2+(3.61/4)a^2+h^2}$ just $s$? In the first equation it's $4*s$. I think you forgot the four.

Comment: @CalebJasik:  you are correct.  I have fixed it.